# C# - Use form instead of messagebox

Tags: c#, messagebox

I am working on an application for work and I need a customized messagebox to appear. I have created a simple form called Alert.cs that I have styled the way I want and added one button with a click method of this.Close(). now I want it to behave exactly like a standard messagebox.show(). I have the form showing but when I use the standard messagebox.show("text of alert") it waits to continue operation until the user click 'OK', this is what I want the form to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to implement a static method for your Alert class if you want the exact MessageBox-like behaviour.

```
public static DialogResult Show(string text)
{
    Alert form = new Alert(text);
    return form.ShowDialog();
}
```

Now you can use the form by calling:

```
Alert.Show("my message");
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! This saves me from needing to create a temporary instance variable just to call it :)

Answer (score 12):

Use `Form.ShowDialog();`. This allows the form to act the same way as a `MessageBox` in the sense that it retains focus until closed.

Comment: Just like to add. You can also set the DialogResult property of the form to match that of a message box.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a modal windows form. Something like

```
Form frm = new Form();
frm.ShowDialog(this);
```

See **[Form.ShowDialog Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx)**

> Shows the form as a modal dialog box
>   with the currently active window set
>   as its owner.

**[Displaying Modal and Modeless Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358(VS.71).aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

You don't write how you currently display your Alert Form, but calling

```
alert.ShowDialog();
```

instead of `alert.Show()` should do the trick.

The ShowDialog that takes an owner is an even better alternative:

```
alert.ShowDialog(owner);
```